# Reading file stream fails in PHP with standard input while using fast cgi with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, postfix-mta, fpm

I had an implementation with email hook setup with postfix in ubuntu server to pipe the incoming email to a script file. The implementation worked fine with apache and PHP 5.6. Recently I migrated the application to nginx with Fast CGI and PHP 7.1 and the email parser stopped working. 
Digging into I could only gather that when execution reaches at following code then it stops there for indefinite period of time:

```
$Parser->setStream(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));
```

I tested fopen("php://stdin","r") in plain php file and behavior was same, it got stuck there for indefinite period of time.

I am using [PHP Mime Email Parser with mailparse](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser). I don't think it is issue with Mail Parser as I ran `fopen("php://stdin", "r")` in separate php file and stops there too.

Here is my complete code:

```
<?php

include('src/Attachment.php');
include('src/CharsetManager.php');
include('src/Charset.php');
//include ('src/Exception.php');
include('src/Middlewares.php');
include('src/Middleware.php');
include('src/MiddlewareStack.php');
include('src/MimePart.php');
include('src/Parser.php');


$attach_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/attachments';
$Parser = new Parser();
$Parser->setStream(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));//Execution hangs here
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();



if (count($attachments)) {
    $from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
    $fromParts = imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist($from, null);

    $from_email = $fromParts[0]->mailbox . "@" . $fromParts[0]->host;
    $attachmentPaths=array();
    foreach ($attachments as $attachmentObj)
    {
        array_push($attachmentPaths,$attach_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$attachmentObj->getFilename());
    }
    $data=array(
        'from_name'=>$fromParts[0]->personal,
        'from'=>$from_email,
        'attachments'=>$attachmentPaths
    );

    $Parser->saveAttachments($attach_dir);

    $Parser->saveAttachments($attach_dir);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"MY_SITE_URL");//MY_SITE_URL is replaced for privacy
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Comment: php: // stdin - standard input stream, nothing can be read from it when working as nginx (php-fpm or cgi).
php: // input - you can read POST data from this stream

Comment: Why this is so?
Also php://input would not contain attachments I think, how can I then read file attachments?

Comment: don't know why. Have you tried it that input will work or not? and have you used `stream_get_contents(STDIN);`?

Comment: Used that too, exactly behaves like php://stdin i.e never ending execution

Comment: Have you try to try-catch any error and log them to some log file? We don't have any error message. We merely know that it stopped. It's not ideal for debugging.

Comment: I have tried using `$hi = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
echo $hi;` this in nginx with php7.2-fpm

Comment: It shows the `Resource id #2` and not got stuck any where.